# Android App to help digitizing point layers on a Tablet

Tags: qgis, digitizing, point, tablet

In QGIS, using a pen on my touchscreen PC I can I can digitize a lot of points (e.g. 14000 pts in 2 hours) faster than with a mouse: without having the attribute form to show up I simply need to touch the screen where the point should be rather than moving the pointer with the mouse and clicking.

Unfortunately, I have a collaborator that does not have a touchscreen PC.

Does anybody knows if:

1. Is there any app for android tablets that can be used to achieve
   the same goal?
2. It is possible in some way to take advantage of the touch screen
   of an Adroid tablet to help digitizing?

Answer (score 1):

For Android there is [QField](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.opengis.qfield), currently in beta.

It is basically QGIS 3 with stripped down touch interface for digitizing.
You can export projects from QGIS to the phone with the [QField Sync plugin](https://github.com/opengisch/qfieldsync)

Comment: Thanks @Norwin. I tried that but I see that you can add points only moving the basemap so that the crossair (that is fixed) will be over what you want to annotate... probably good for data collection on the field but not what I'm looking for. At least that is what I understood... is it correct?

Comment: I see your point, tapping can be significantly faster. Last I checked this was the only input method though. Maybe you can [suggest it](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues?q=is%3Aissue+tap+is%3Aclosed) to the developers?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [NextGIS Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextgis.mobile).

It allows you to move point by touch, or move point to the current GPS location or to the cross in the center of the screen and capture coordinates to get average position with accuracy estimation. Also supported other types of geometry (lines, polygons, etc.)

You can add your spatial data from a file source or connect from cloud GIS ([nextgis.com](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html)). Layers from nextgis.com sync automatically - useful for team field works.

Additionally you can attach photos to points and design you own form to fill attributes if standard not suits you. For custom forms use [FormBuilder](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-formbuilder) desktop application.

Documentation for NextGIS Mobile available here: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngmobile/source/toc.html

FOSS4G Bonn 2016 presentation [video](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/FOSS4G-2016/foss4g-2016-1233-nextgis_mobile_-_mobile_gis_alternative-hd.mp4).

**Disclosure**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Comment: This appears to be commercial but open source.  Can you clarify this?  i.e. is it "freemium" or somesuch?

Comment: Yes your are right - this is [opensource](https://github.com/nextgis/android_gisapp) application. Most of functions available for free (according to your post I think free functionality will be enough). There are some functions available only for commercial users (for example, editing external PostGIS layers in a cloud) and other usual commercial features (like direct support, prioritised bug-fixing, etc.).

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I'll have to look into using it for field work.